# How do I get same result without using enumerate?

Tags: for-loop, python, enumerate

I do not need `char` in this example, but I include it to get my desired results.

```
charlist = [strval[0:count+1] for count, char in enumerate(strval)]
```

How do I get the same result without using **enumerate**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
xrange(len(strval))
```

Comment: If using Python3, just plain ol' `range` will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use enumerate, `use range` since all you want is count value

```
>>> strval = "abcd"
>>> for count, char in enumerate(strval): print count, char
... 
0 a
1 b
2 c
3 d
>>> for count in range(len(strval)): print count
... 
0
1
2
3
>>>
```

Comment: I now know xrange is better than range :)

Answer (score 0):

How about replacing `enumerate(...)` with `zip(xrange(...),...)`?

```
[strval[0:count+1] for count, char in zip(xrange(len(strval)),strval)]
```

Comment: `char` is never used. The problem is not that `enumerate()` is unavailable, but that it's wasted effort.